# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint Import Data

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am importing data from one database to another database with same table structure  using `Task - Import Data`  .  i always getting error `INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint` . I want that when i import data i not get this error . [image: import like this] . 
Is this possible that  i delete all the foreign key from the table and after import i run the script for foreign key to the table , if yes how can i do that . Thanks for your reply and comments

Comment: The foreign key is there for a reason. The data you are importing must first have referenced data in the table the FK is referencing, before you import it. You can use `sp_help` to see what column has a FK if you can't see it in the object explorer in Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest importing raw data into a staging table, which has no FK constraints.  Then from there, you can quickly query the staging area, and determine which values are violating the FK constraints.

Ex. you create a table called `tblImport`, and the FK is on the field `city`.  Your `city` table only has New York and Los Angeles, but when you `select distinct city from tblImport` you see Las Vegas is also there.  Las Vegas is violating your constraint.  You can then add Las Vegas to your `city` table, and import with out violating the FK constraint.

Once you have imported into the final destination, drop the `tblImport`.

I should also add, that you cannot drop the FK, import, then re-add the FK.  The operation to re-add the FK will check the constraint, and fail.

You need to either 1) add a relationship entry that allows the import as I suggested above or 2) write an import script that satisfies the constraints of the FK, and only imports records where a relationship exists (ie. it would only import New York and Los Angeles).